# Rails contact form not sending email

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to set up a simple contact form in the footer of my application.
The form validation works, but I am not receiving an email.

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.murdo.ch/blog/build-a-contact-form-with-ruby-on-rails-part-1) but changed a couple things because the contact form is in footer, rather than in `messages/new.html.erb` page, which in my app doesn't exist.

My routes file has the following:

```
post 'contact-me', to: 'messages#create', as: 'create_message'
```

Here is the message model (without migration), controller, and mailer:

```
# message.rb
class Message
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :name, :email, :body
  validates :name, :email, :body, presence: true
end

# messages_controller.rb
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    message_params = params.require(:message).permit(:name, :email, :body)
    @message = Message.new message_params

    if @message.valid?
      MessageMailer.contact_me(@message).deliver_now
      flash[:success] = "Message sent"
      redirect_to :back
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Message not sent. Please fill in all fields."
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

end

# message_mailer.rb
class MessageMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def contact_me(message)
    @body = message.body

    # Note: my actual email is here, I just omitted it for this question
    mail to: "<my-email>", from: message.email
  end

end
```

Since contact form is on every page of the view, I made the new action in ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper

  before_filter :get_message

  def get_message
    @message = Message.new
  end

end
```

_footer.html.erb partial renders the contact form:

```
# shared/_contact_form.html.erb
<%= form_for @message, url: create_message_url do |f| %>
  <%= notice %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'name' %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: 'email' %>
  <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: 'body' %>
  <%= f.submit 'Send' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: what is your smtp setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following smtp setting on `config/application.rb` file:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://www.xxxx.com' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port => 587,
      :domain => "gmail.com",
      :user_name => "xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
      :password => "xxxxxxxx",
      :authentication => "plain",
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what to put as host. I am using cloud9.

Comment: host is the link to your website. whats the link of cloud9 of your app, try to add it.

Comment: add line: config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true and check the error messages

Comment: If you run into errors like Net::SMTPAuthenticationError while using gmail for sending out emails (common for Google Apps accounts), visit your gmail settings and enable less secure apps to get the application working. Link: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: Ok got it. Thank you!! :)